# Join multiple threads with timeout

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to join multiple threads with a timeout. Something like `Thread.join(long millis)` but for multiple threads.

I found some posts about joining multiple threads, but not regarding joining with timeout.

The code I'm changing is:

```
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.join(units.toMillis(timeout));
}
```

But this obviously waits for each thread separately having the effect of waiting up to `threads.length * timeout`. I want to wait up to `timeout` for all threads altogether.

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: This seems a little vague. Could you post the code that you have so far.

Comment: @bhspencer I'll add the code to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to implement a barrier with a timeout. Have you tried this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Comment: From what I read about CyclicBarrier each thread has to invoke the `await()` method by itself, and I want one thread to wait for other threads to finish. Assuming I don't control the other threads, how can use CyclicBarrier for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can track elapsed time and join on timeout - elapsed, if it's negative, you don't need to wait at all, it's time-outed already